# C++ Vector addition - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'SUMA_C' was corrupted

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, compiler-errors, calculator

I'm on my first college year and we've been asked to make multiple calculators, first we used simple codes, then we got introduced to modules and now we're doing it with vectors. My problem is that when I try to add two numbers (which are integers) and the result of that is bigger than 10, it either literraly skips the position, meaning for example 8 + 8. It would just save the 1 and then go straight to the next addition deleting the 6. Or, it skips the next addition, for example, if I did 8+8 and then 1+1 the result of the last one would vanish.

I declared a new type called vector which stores numbers up to 102 on each "position".

```
const int MAX = 102;

typedef int vector[MAX];
```

What the module that I'm going to show you now does is to take two different vectors:

The first [] stores only 0 and 1. I use this position to know if the number is positive(0) or negative(1).

The second [] stores the size of the vector, ignoring the two first [] because I don't use them to store the user input.

```
Z[0] [8] [][][][][][][][]
X[0] [8] [][][][][][][][]
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
Z[0] [3] [8][8][4]
X[0] [3] [8][8][4]
```

And then, the assign the addition of each [] to a new vector on the same exact position. But we've been told that we can only store numbers from 0 to 9 on each []. Which means if I get a result > 10. I will have to split it on two so I can store each part on a [].

giving this as a result:

W[0] [5] [1][6][1][6][8].

```
void SUMM(vector Z, vector X, vector W) {

int suma;
AZERO(W);

for (int i = 2; i <= MAX; i++)
{
    SUMA_INT(W[i], 0, suma);
    SUMA_INT(Z[i],X[i],suma);

    if (suma > 9)
    {
        W[i] = suma / 10;
        W[i + 1] = suma % 10;
        //i++;
        //Z[i - 1] = Z[i - 1] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        W[i] = suma;
    }

    suma = 0;

}   compta_xifres(W);}
```

SUMA_INT(Adds this, and this, to this)

compta_xifres(W) basically tells the size of the vector. And assigns it to the position 1 of a vector: vector[1]

Comment: What is `vector`? What is `AZERO(W)`? `compta_xifres(W);`? `MAX`? Please post a [mre], there is much that _looks_ wrong, but we can't be sure without context.

Comment: You need to show more context. I expect MAX is the size of your vectors so you are accessing one maybe 2 past the end. `W[i + 1] = suma % 10;` looks like 2 past the end, unless MAX is W.size() -2

Comment: True, my bad. Should've said it.

Comment: Sidenote: `int suma;` is never initialized, reading it causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @churill AZERO(W) assigns 0 to every single [] of W (except 0 and 1)

Comment: @drescherjm Exactly! I honestly don't understand what you mean with 2 past the end. On this case the i value is determined by the for so I assign the suma % 10 to the W[5] for example. Which would be then W[5] = 15 % 10  = 5.

Comment: The last valid index is `MAX - 1`, but `i` can go up to `MAX` and you use `i + 1` later, which is out of bounds by 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: @churill Wow I dind't think about that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @drescherjm I think I understand now, thank you very much